# Upgrading from Gitlab 13.11.4 to Gitlab 14.2.3

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I change GitLab docker image to latest version but after run, service doesn't start and just log this, What should I do?

```
    Current version: gitlab-ce=14.2.3-ce.0
    
    Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
    And restart this container to reload settings.
    To do it use docker exec:
    
      docker exec -it gitlab editor /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
      docker restart gitlab
    
    For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
    https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md
    
    If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:
    
      docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
      docker restart gitlab
    
    Cleaning stale PIDs & sockets
    It seems you are upgrading from major version 13 to major version 14.
    It is required to upgrade to the latest 14.0.x version first before proceeding.
    Please follow the upgrade documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrading-to-a-new-major-version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade version steps:
8.11.Z -> 8.12.0 -> 8.17.7 -> 9.5.10 -> 10.8.7 -> 11.11.8 -> 12.0.12 -> 12.1.17 -> 12.10.14 -> 13.0.14 - > 13.1.11 -> 13.8.8 -> latest 13.12.Z -> latest 14.0.Z -> 14.1.Z -> latest 14.Y.Z

Comment: why ? Why pass through all versions ? Also, he is already in 13.11.4 so he doesn't need the first step

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: yes, but I write complete version steps for upgrade!

Comment: @MohammadReza, I see you are new to Stack Exchange. Normally you don't let others find the issue, write elaborate answers, then write your own answer based on that and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is already in your post:

> It seems you are upgrading from major version 13 to major version 14.
> It is required to upgrade to the latest 14.0.x version first before proceeding.
> Please follow the upgrade documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrading-to-a-new-major-version

[This](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#upgrade-paths) gives more information.

Ideally, you should:

1. take a backup of your data folder
2. upgrade to `13.12.11-ce` (the last minor of your current major release)
3. upgrade to `14.0.10-ce` (the first minor of the new major release)
4. upgrade to `14.2.3-ce` (your target, i.e. the last minor of the new major release)

Check [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) for an up-to-date list of docker images.

Comment: THX @cornuz but ,after upgrade to 14.2.3-ce have this error:  ``` Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:
rails_migration[gitlab-rails] (gitlab::database_migrations line 51) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/resources/rails_migration.rb line 16) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20210906-30-1ha3n27" ----
STDOUT: rake aborted!

```

Comment: If you mean after your first failed attempt from 13.11.4 directly to 14.2.3, then you should start over with the correct procedure, from a backup that you hopefully have. If you mean after the correct procedure, then I would ask them, possibly opening an issue on Gitlab itself.

Comment: I upgraded by steps you said in final step(14.2.3-ce), I have this error!; now my gitlab version is 14.0.10-ce and it works.